# Loop through the columns and avoid IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Given sample data set (real data has `(931, 674)`):

```
12_longitude_1  12_latitude_1   14_longitude_2  14_latitude_2   15_longitude_3  15_latitude_3
           16             11             12               13             14              15     
           16             11             12               13             14              15  
           16             11             12               13             14              15
```

I am running:

```
pd_out = pd.DataFrame({'zone': [], 'number': []})

for col_num in range(0, len(border.columns), 2):
    curr_lon_name = border.columns[col_num]
    curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1] # PROBLEM IS HERE
    num = curr_lon_name.split("_")[-1]
    border = border[[curr_lon_name, curr_lat_name]].dropna()
    border[curr_lon_name] = border[curr_lon_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lat_name] = border[curr_lat_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lon_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lon_name], errors='coerce')
    border[curr_lat_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lat_name], errors='coerce')
    geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border[curr_lon_name],border[curr_lat_name])]
    border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
    turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
    within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
    curr_len = len(within_turin)
    pd_out = pd_out.append({'zone': "long_lat_{}".format(num), 'number': curr_len}, ignore_index=True)
```

---

But in the line `----> 7     curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1]` I get:

> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Comment: can u tell me why you are iterating alternate column in range(0, len(border.columns), 2) gives you alternate column and it's look like you don't have 3rd index in border.columns

Comment: try this in the for statement: for col_num in range(0, len(border.columns)-1, 2)

Comment: @giulio something good! But output was only 1 row, but I need 338 (as I am working with every 2 couples)

Answer (score 0):

Python starts indexing at 0. So if your axis is of size 3, then you can only access it with indices 0, 1, and 2.

`len(border.columns)` is (I presume) 3. And so `col_num` will take values 0 and 2 in your for loop.

When it takes value 2, and then you do `border.columns[col_num + 1]` in your problematic line, you are trying to access the axis outside of its bounds, as `col_num+1` is 3.

Comment: Thus, what should I do?